# Recaptcha replaces Formmail's "email" (From) field with my server address. Without Recaptcha, From field works fine. Why?

Tags: server, recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha, formmail

I've been using Tectite Formmail.php for many years. Finally added Recaptcha ver 2 (Invisible mode).  It works okay, except that it messes with the ***derive_fields*** email string.  Without Captcha, the results email's ***From*** field **properly** contains the name and email address of the person who filled out my form, that is a value derived from "realname" and "email".

> e.g., *Ralph Waldo <rwaldoexample@gmail.com*

When I enable ReCaptcha, the results email's ***From*** field undesirably shows my hosting account username and server address:

> e.g., *username@1a2b3c45.prod.phx1.example.net

If I revert the form to a standard  tag and disable Recaptcha (by nulling the $REQUIRE_CAPTCHA and $RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY values as in code shown below), I get the desired ***From*** contents as I used to. This behavior is the same for Formmail v 9.15 and 9.19.

**If this is standard procedure for Recaptcha, it seems undocumented.  If not, what's the fix?**

```
SNIPPETS, PER REQUEST:

In web page header:
<!-- CAPTCHA Ver2 Invisible  -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        document.getElementById("Contact_Form").submit();
    }
</script>
<!-- end CAPTCHA -->
```

---

```
In web page HTML
<form id="Contact_Form" action="https://www.example.com/formmail.php" method="post" name="Formtype 1">
<input name="good_url" value="https://www.example.com/tnxpg.html" type="hidden" />
<INPUT NAME="subject" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="~~FORM RECEIVED - Main mail form">
<!-- OTHER INFO TO APPEAR IN EMAIL -->
<input type="hidden"  name="form_version" value="Visitor used Main Form">
<input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="FromAddr=formmssg1@example.com" />

<!-- DON'T CHANGE THE FOLLOWING ... EXCEPT put actual field names after equals signs. -->
<!-- this derives (creates) "email" and "realname" special fields from the input fields -->
<input type="hidden" name="derive_fields" value="email=EmailAddr,realname=FullName" />

<!-- DON'T CHANGE THE FOLLOWING! -->
    <!-- this excludes the "email" and "realname" special fields from the body of the email you receive -->
    <input type="hidden" name="mail_options" value="Exclude=email;realname" >
<input name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT,AUTH_TYPE,REMOTE_USER" type="hidden" />

* * *

<input type="hidden" name="derive_fields" value="imgverify=g-recaptcha-response" />

<!-- with this simple Submit tag and the private key removed from Formmail.php, results email From is correct -->
<!--
<input type="submit" value=" Send message ">
-->

<input type="submit" value=" Send Message " class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="onSubmit" data-sitekey="PublicKeyGoesHere" / >
```

---

```
In formmail.php:

/* Help: http://www.tectite.com/fmdoc/require_captcha.php */
//// DO NOT USE CAPTCHA
//// $REQUIRE_CAPTCHA = ""; /* set to a message string if your forms */
//// USE CAPTCHA
$REQUIRE_CAPTCHA = "Confirm you are not a robot."; 
/* set to a message string if your forms must provide a CAPTCHA string*/

/* Help: http://www.tectite.com/fmdoc/recaptcha_private_key.php */
//// DO NOT USE CAPTCHA
//$RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = "";
//// USE CAPTCHA
$RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = "myprivatekeygoeshere";
```

Comment: Would you be able to add a snippet of your implementation & form so we can help debug?

Comment: I will be happy to do so, but must first find a bit more time to anonymize it. Actually, the problem is not with the form, nor I doubt with my implementation. It works fine until I enable the Recaptcha, and the code for that is standard stuff, too.  One thing I forgot to mention (until my edit) was that it is Invisible recaptcha. So without some kludgy testing as directed by Tectite, or a reduction in form abuse incidents, I have no way of knowing if it the captcha actually works.  But the form works as usual, just with this aberration in the mail header's From field.

Answer (score 0):

This is unusual behaviour.

I suspect there's a syntax error in your HTML and that's causing the damage to the form submission.

You should validate your HTML at https://validator.w3.org/